# OpenCV change RGB parameters in rectangle

Tags: java, android, opencv, rgb

I have 4 points. For example...

```
A(1;1)
B(2;5)
C(4;4)
D(3;2)
```

How I can change RGB parameters in this rectangle (for all pixels)?

Like this:

```
double[] data = mat.get(x, y);
data[0] = data[0]+30;
data[1] = data[1]+20;
data[2] = data[2]+10;
mat.put(x, y, data);
```

Comment: Probably best approach would be creating a mask by drawing a filled polygon determined by the 4 points. Then, use that mask in, say, [`Core.add`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#add(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))...

Comment: @DanMašek I'll try use polygon. But it draw only new Scaral. I need add +10 red for all pixels

Comment: The drawing of the polygon is only to create a mask, which is used to update only the desired points. The second step is to add a Scalar to the Mat, using that mask to limit which pixels get modified.

Comment: @DanMašek My bad. I was in a hurry and did not read the question properly.

Comment: @DanMašek can you write example, please? ))) In Java code))

Comment: @SergeyRokitskiy I think Andrii's answer almost covers it, it certainly does the job. There are some ways to optimize it, as I mentioned in the comment under his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that for implementing approach described in [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) comment:

```
...
Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.<your_image>);
Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);

Mat maskMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
Mat resultMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

// create color, which added to sourceMat region (+100 - for red channel)
Scalar color = new Scalar(100, 0, 0, 255);

// or you can try Scalar color = new Scalar(10, 20, 30);  as in your question

Point[] region = new Point[4];

// your coords multiplied by 50 for visualization convenience
region[0] = new Point(50, 50);
region[1] = new Point(100, 250);
region[2] = new Point(200, 200);
region[3] = new Point(150, 100);

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList();
MatOfPoint regionMat = new MatOfPoint(region);
contours.add(regionMat);

// create mask    
Imgproc.drawContours(maskMat, contours, 0, color, -1);

// apply mask to source
Core.add(maskMat, sourceMat, resultMat);

// just for visualisation
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat.cols(), sourceMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(resultMat, bitmap);

<your_ImageView>.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
...
```

NB! This is just example of masking, not optimized.

Comment: I'd keep the mask as a single channel image, and use the overload of `Core.add` that takes a scalar: `Core.add(sourceMat, Scalar(10,20,30), sourceMat, maskMat)`. Good idea with `drawContours`.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko It fill figure to one color, but don't add +100 only to RED chanel. (Это работает не так как хотелось. Оно просто заполняет фигуру по координатам одним цветом. А мне надо что б было чисто добавление к красному каналу значение. Что б было никая прозрачность... Типа фильтр на губы... Чуть добавить красного...  Если поймешь русскую речь, помоги плз)))

Comment: It works exactly as you ask in question: adds R, G and B values to ALL pixels of rectangle region (there is no transparency - that effect is only color change for "non red" pixels). Seems you need not add value to red channel, but add value to red pixels. If you want to change color of only red pixels (add more red to only red) then you should use not rectangle mask, but mask for red pixels. To do that you should convert image to HSV, then use [`Core.inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) to create mask for only red pixels. It's other question.

Comment: @DanMašek "I'd keep the mask as a single channel image, and use the overload of `Core.add`" - that is better approach, of course.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko No. I need to select a piece of the image and change all the pixels of this piece and increase the value of the red channel. For example, a pixel had parameters (125, 50, 58), and I want to do (125 + (n), 50, 58). And so for each pixel in the given piece.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I did this, but I did it on two rectangular points. And then with the help (for) passed through all the pixels. But now I need to do the same, but not with a rectangle.

Comment: The code above exactly increase the value of the red channel (and other G and B if `new Scalar()` has not 0 values for G and B channels). To check it you can use `double[] data = mat.get(x, y);` and print to log `data[0] - red, data[1] - green and data[2] - blue` for same `x` and `y` before and after applying mask.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko If I could, I'd show you a screenshot. I can not add pictures yet. The code above does not add +100 to the ipexel, but simply makes the pixel parameters (100, 0, 0)

Comment: Why a screenshot? Just get pixel color  with `(x,y)` coords `double[] data = mat.get(x, y);` before and after applying mask. You will see, that channels values increased exactly by mask values.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i see on phone screen red "rectangle"

Comment: Did you modify code? How do you get the `sourceMat`? May be `CvType` wrong?

Comment: Your code is wrong: at least, you use SAME `Mat` object for source, mask and result. You should create new objects for mask and `resultMat`. Or you think that I add `Mat maskMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);` line just for fun?  Do not complicate - at first, just add picture to your project `drawable` folder and check code above. And then decide what to do.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i using realtime mat from camera

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer due to comment below:**

This is OpenCV C++ code but you can easily port it to JAVA. Also my code assumes the points always represent a rectangle.

```
// read image
Mat image=imread("image.jpg",-1);

// region of interest, shape=rectangle
Point p1(50,50), p2(100,80);
Rect roi(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y);

// vector hold channels
std::vector<Mat> channels(3);

// split original image to bgr channels
cv::split(image, channels);

// Mat to hold ROI
Mat extractedRoi;

//For channel B
extractedRoi = channels.at(0)(roi);
extractedRoi += 30;

//For channel G
extractedRoi = channels.at(1)(roi);
extractedRoi += 20;

//For channel R
extractedRoi = channels.at(2)(roi);
extractedRoi += 10;

// merge channels back together
cv::merge(channels, image);
```

**Edit2**: A faster approach.

```
Mat image=imread("/home/haseebullah/Pictures/S1.jpg",-1);

Point p1(50,50), p2(100,80);
Rect roi(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y);

Mat extractedRoi;

extractedRoi = image(roi);

Scalar constants(30,20,10);

extractedRoi += constants
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP wants to offset all the pixels in the region by a constant, and leave the rest unmodified. Also notice that the 4 points don't make a rectangle with horizontal and vertical edges, so `cv::rectangle` is not going to help.

Comment: @DanMašek Please check now.

Comment: @DanMašek That's pretty good actually. Mine is too compute intensive than your answer. I added a faster approach, but my answers assume that the points represent a rectangle.